# EF5.x with Power Tools 3.x Beta

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I did a Reveres code Eng inner to generate code first using the EF power tools for MYSQL DB 
i can read tables very well.
when i try to save anything i get exception below.  i do not set this field nor do i have anything in my solution by this field name.

```
            ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext();
            Person person = new Person();
            person.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            person.UserId = 1;
            person.PersonName = "test";
            db.Persones.Add(person);

            db.SaveChanges();

{"Unknown column 'Discriminator' in 'field list'"}
```

**EDIT**
I noticed that i had another class which was inheriting this class

public class Student:Person
{

}

when i removed that inheritance it worked .
but does anyone know why?
any ideas?

Comment: check the generated context and pocos.  You most likely had a db that resulted in a Table Per Hierarchy outcome.  Perhaps the generated code needs a tweak.  We cant see the interesting part.   The why TPH, see http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx  as an example explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this field is automatically added when you have one class that inherits from other. This field is used so EF can know witch record represent Student and witch records are only persons.

[This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) that is mentioned by [soadyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1347784/soadyp) explain this better.

Models created with codefirst use TPH by default.